# What is another way to approach this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given this inequality to solve today and then somebody showed me a very clever and simple way to solve it. They made two assumptions and with both of those assumptions, they deduced the proper interval of the inequality. I tried to replicate their method, but I was not successful.

This is how I solved it, but I would like to see that "assumptions" method again. It seemed more efficient.

Steps I took:

$$\frac { 2x }{ x-3 } <1\\ $$

Finding the critical points: $$\frac { 2x }{ x-3 } =1\\ $$

$$2x=x-3$$

Critical points are: $$x=3\quad or\quad x=-3$$

Testing around the critical points shows that the interval is $(-3,3)$

Can someone show me the "two assumptions" method?

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what the two assumptions are? There are several ways of solving this question, you showed one, and now you are asking us "what is the other one?". That's like saying "I know New York is a city in USA, but what is the other city in the USA?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it was this?
$$
\begin{cases}
x-3>0\\
2x<x-3
\end{cases}
\qquad \lor \qquad 
\begin{cases}
x-3<0\\
2x>x-3
\end{cases}
$$
so that:

$$
\left(\begin{cases}
x>3\\
x<-3
\end{cases}
\qquad \lor \qquad 
\begin{cases}
x<3\\
x>-3
\end{cases}\right)
\iff -3<x<3
$$

Comment: That was it! He used different notation, but I believe this was it. 
Can you please show me all the steps to this?

Comment: Simply multiply for $x-3$ dividing the two case $x-3>0$ and $x-3<0$, and remember that multipling an inequality by a negative number reverse  the inequality.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how multiplying both sides by $x-3$ leads to two cases. I can see one case, where $x<-3$, but not the other case. 

I apologize. I'm having one of those days where even simple concepts are hard to understand.

Comment: Given an inequality $A<B$ ($2<5$) if we multiply both sides for a positive number $C>0$ ( $C=3$) the order remain the same, i.e. we have $AC<BC$ ( $6<15$). If we multiply for a negative number $C<0$ ($C=-3$)the order is reversed $AC>BC$ ($-6>-15$). In our case we are multiplying by $x-3$ that can be positive $x-3>0 \iff x>3$ or negative $x-3<0 \iff x<3$, so we have two case.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the assumptions were on whether $x<3$ or $x>3$.

- If $x<3$, then $x-3<0$, meaning that $$\frac{2x}{x-3}<1 \iff 2x > x-3\iff x>-3$$
  meaning that $x\in(-3,3)$.
- If $x>3$, then $x-3 > 0$, meaning that $$\frac{2x}{x-3} < 1 \iff 2x < x-3 \iff x<-3$$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Divide it into two cases (clearly $x=3$ doesn't make sense).

*Case 1:* $x > 3$

Multiply both sides of the equality by $x-3$ to get

$$2x < x-3,$$

which is equivalent to

$$x < -3.$$

This is a contradiction, so the first case brings no solutions with it.

*Case 2:* $x < 3$

Multiply both sides with the same, but flip the inequality to get

$$2x > x-3,$$

or

$x > -3$.

In conclusion, the set of solutions is $\{x\ |-3<x<3\}$.

Comment: Why do you flip the inequality for the second case?

Comment: It is because of the general rule that if $a/c < b/c$, and if $c$ is negative, then I can multiply both sides by $c$ to get $a > b$, but with the inequality flipped. For instance, we have that $6/(-3) < 3/(-3)$, but $6>3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { 2x }{ x-3 } <1\Rightarrow \frac { 2x }{ x-3 } -1=\frac { 2x-x+3 }{ x-3 }= \frac { x+3 }{ x-3 }<0 $$

$\frac { x+3 }{ x-3 }<0\iff{ (x+3 )}{ (x-3 )}<0$

Note that: $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ with $a<b\implies a<x<b$